# Add a linebreak in an HTML text area

Tags: html

How can i add a line break to the text area in a html page?
i use VB.net for server side coding.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If it's not vb you can use `&#013;&#010;` (ascii codes for cr,lf)

Comment: I think the generic solution should be the accepted one. Or adding a vb.net tag to the question.

Comment: This helped me echo line breaks into my textarea with AJAX and PHP, for example: `echo $content.'&#013;&#010;&#013;&#010;database text'`

Comment: This solution will work only if you type the ascii codes in the body of the textarea itself IN the html code itself.  If you insert these codes via javascript, e.value=" this&#013;&#010;that" they will simply appear right in the text of the textarea as raw untranslated symbols.  There is another answer below (Loren Segal) that correctly suggests that you can put "\n" in the string that you are inserting in the textarea that will translate to line breaks.

eg: document.getElementById("myTextArea").value = "this \n that";

Answer (score 22):

Add a linefeed ("\n") to the output:

```
<textarea>Hello


Bybye</textarea>
```

Will have a newline in it.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `\r\n`, or `System.Environment.NewLine`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're inserting text from a database or such (which one usually do), convert all "`<br />`"'s to &vbCrLf. Works great for me :)

Answer (score 3):

In a text area, as in the form input, then just a normal line break will work:

```
<textarea>
This is a text area
line breaks are automatic
</textarea>
```

If you're talking about normal text on the page, the <br /> (or just <br> if using plain 'ole HTML4) is a line break.

However, I'd say that you often don't actually want a line break. Usually, your text is seperated into paragraphs:

```
<p>
  This is some text
</p>
<p>
  This is some more
</p>
```

Which is much better because it gives a clue as to how your text is structured to machines that read it. Machines that read it include screen readers for the partially sighted or blind, seperating text into paragraphs gives it a chance of being presented correctly to these users.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will work:

```
TextArea.Text = "Line 1" & vbCrLf & "Line 2"
```

System.Environment.NewLine could be used in place of vbCrLf if you wanted to be a little less VB6 about it.

Answer (score 1):

Escape sequences like "\n" work fine ! even with text area! I passed a java string with the "\n" to a html textarea  and it worked fine as it works on consoles for java!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my method made with pure PHP and CSS :

```
/** PHP code    */
<?php
    $string = "the string with linebreaks";
    $string = strtr($string,array("."=>".\r\r",":"=>" : \r","-"=>"\r - "));
?>
```

And the CSS :

```
.your_textarea_class {
style='white-space:pre-wrap';
}
```

You can do the same with regex (I'm learning how to build regex with pregreplace using an associative array, seems to be better for adding the \n\r which makes the breaks display).