# How to add line breaks to an HTML textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, line-breaks

I’m editing a `<textarea>` with JavaScript. The problem is that when I make line breaks in it, they won’t display. How can I do this?

I’m getting the value to write a function, but it won’t give line breaks.

Comment: Codepen demo with regex and `<pre></pre>` solutions exposed here: https://codepen.io/a-guerrero/pen/grgVBo

Answer (score 309, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that line breaks (`\n\r`?) are not the same as HTML `<br/>` tags:

```
var text = document.forms[0].txt.value;
text = text.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
```

Since many of the comments and my own experience have shown me that this `<br>` solution is not working as expected, here is an example of how to append a new line to a `textarea` using '\r\n':

```
function log(text) {
    var txtArea;

    txtArea = document.getElementById("txtDebug");
    txtArea.value += text + '\r\n';
}
```

Comment: This works for me too. In jQuery you can do something like this: $('#caption').html($('#caption').text().replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />'));

Comment: The line break Regexp should be `/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm`
http://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/javascript-line-breaks.php

Comment: If you are using jQuery I suggest using `.val` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583040/show-newlines-in-html-textarea/5583094#5583094

Comment: The right regex is `/\r\n?|\n/g` without capture, no multiline.

Comment: Suspect `<br>` is wrong. For a **universal line break in a textarea** you want `\r\n`.  For example, the UC Browser ignores <br> and \n in textareas.  See [Add a linebreak in an HTML text area](http://stackoverflow.com/q/66773/673991).

Comment: Using <br> inside of a textarea is not working. At least not in Chrome, where I tested. Using \n seem to work though. Use <br> if you intend to insert the text as pure html, i.e. outside of any input element.

Comment: .value=your new text with \r\n wont work inside TEXTAREA tag, need to use .innerHTML=your new text with \r\n

Answer (score 25):

If you use general JavaScript and you need to assign a string to a text area value, then
document.getElementById("textareaid").value='texthere\\ntexttext'.

You need to replace `\n` or `< br >` with `\\\n`.

Otherwise, it gives *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL* in all browsers.

Answer (score 22):

You need to use `\n` for `linebreaks` inside `textarea`

Comment: Works in Firefox v71. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

I had a problem with line breaks which were passed from a server variable to a JavaScript variable, and then JavaScript was writing them to a textarea (using [KnockoutJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KnockoutJS) value bindings).

The solution was double escaping new lines:

```
original.Replace("\r\n", "\\r\\n")
```

on the server side, because with just single escape characters, JavaScript was not parsing.

Comment: using "\\n" works for me in Windows and I assume it will work fine in Linux systems.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to display text inside your own page, you can use the `<pre>` tag.

```js
document.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  document.querySelector('pre').innerText = this.value;
});
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="type text here"></textarea>
<pre style="font-family: inherits">
The
new lines will
be respected
      and spaces too
</pre>
```

Comment: Great tip, instead of doing crlf replacement I used this in my C# by pre/appending to text area string in code

Answer (score 5):

I have a textarea whose id is **#infoartist**, as follows:

```
<textarea id="infoartist" ng-show="dForm" style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Tell your contacts and collectors about yourself."></textarea>
```

In JavaScript code, I’ll get the value of the textarea and replace escaping a new line (\n\r) by the `<br />` tag, such as:

```
var text = document.getElementById("infoartist").value;
text = text.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
```

So if you are using [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) (like me):

```
var text = $("#infoartist").val();
text = text.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
```

Answer (score 2):

A new line is just whitespace to the browser and won't be treated any different to a normal space (" "). To get a new line, you must insert `<BR />` elements.

Another attempt to solve the problem: Type the text into the textarea and then add some JavaScript behind a button to convert the invisible characters to something readable and dump the result to a `DIV`. That will tell you what your browser wants.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to send the value of the textarea to the server with line breaks, use [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing I did for the same trouble I had.

When I'm passing the text to the next page in [JSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Server_Pages), I’m reading it as a textarea instead of reading something like

```
<s:property value="%{text}"/>
```

so the output came as you wanted.

And for other properties, you can use it as below.

```
<textarea style="background-color: white; border: none; width:660px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:1.0em; resize:none;" name="text" cols="75" rows="15" readonly="readonly" ><s:property value="%{text}"/></textarea>
```