# inserting line breaks in text quoted in javascript

Tags: javascript, textarea, line-breaks

Doing some text swapping (testimonials fade in/out) with JavaScript and want to insert the equivalent of a `<br/>` inside the quotes so the author of the quote is on the next line. In the below code, I tried following the instructions at [JavaScript: How to add line breaks to an HTML textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863779/textarea-line-breaks-javascript), but am not sure how to insert `/\n\r?/g` to make it work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var text = document.forms[0].txt.value;
    text = text.replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    window.testimonials = [
        '"This was a great experience" /\n\r?/g - Max Cameron, ThinkTank',
        '"This was a great experience" /\n\r?/g - Max Cameron, ThinkTank',
        "source code"
    ];
</script>
```

Is there any way to force it onto the next line? Thanks!

Comment: if you are inserting the `/\n\r?/g` (as it sounds you are) why not just use the text you DO want (`<br/>`) or, are those testimonials coming from a source you cannot edit?

Answer (score 3):

you are doing something really weird here. why are you inserting a 'regex' into your variables?

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4Fheu/

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var text = window.testimonial; // or maybe: document.forms[0].txt.value;
    text = text.replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />');
    alert(text);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    window.testimonials = [
        '"This was a great experience" \n - Max Cameron, ThinkTank',
        '"This was a great experience" \n - Max Cameron, ThinkTank',
        "source code"
    ];
</script>
```

`/\n\r?/` is a regex that says: 'newline' followed by 0 or 1 'carriage return'.

the value `'/\n\r?/'` is a string that might look like this:

/
/

Answer (score 0):

[Borrowing from what you linked to:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/863806/465546)

```
window.testimonials = [
'"This was a great experience" /\n\r?/g - Max Cameron, ThinkTank'.replace(/(\n\r?)|(,)/g, '<br />');,
'"This was a great experience" /\n\r?/g - Max Cameron, ThinkTank'.replace(/(\n\r?)|(,)/g, '<br />');,
"source code"];
```

Comment: hm, that completely breaks the text swapping functionality. Is there any other way?

Comment: Still no go :\ Is there any other script you recommend for swapping testimonials with a fade transition?

Comment: It's not working because you're putting regex into a string.  If you remove the `/`, and the `?/g` from the string.. it should work.