# javascript/html/php capture linebreaks in textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea, line-breaks

I am desperately trying to capture the line breaks in a textarea.  I want to store the contents of the textarea in a database and then display it in a textarea when pulled from the database.  The textarea should serve as an editing box.  At no point do I need to display in html.

I was able to get this to work on a normal html page that posts the textarea content to a server by converting the text from the textarea into an array of lines, exploding on the characters \r\n, and imploding it into a comma delimited list of lines. Then when I want to redisplay the lines, I replace the commas with \n and get text with line breaks that I can display inside a textarea.  A bit of a hack but it works.

However, it does not seem to work when instead of posting the textarea contents to the server using html, I pull them using getElementByID in javascript and then post to the server in javascript.

When I get the textarea contents using html and explode on \r\n I get an array with as many elements as lines.

However, when I pull the textarea contents using getElementByID in javascript, and explode on \r\n, I just get one element in the array where the lines run on.  In other words, I do not get the linebreaks

Anyone know why the linebreaks would disappear when pulling the text in javascript and have any suggestions on how to preserve line breaks in javascript?

Thanks.

Abbreviated code:
javascript

```
getText() {

var textobj = document.getElementById("text");
var text = textobj.value;

...some code for AJAX


    document.getElementById("droptext").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
... some more code for Ajax

xmlhttp.open("GET","savetext.php?text="+text,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

html

```
<div id="droptext"><textarea id="text"><textarea></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getText();">Save Text</a>
```

php

```
$text = $_GET['text'];
$textarray = explode("\r\n", $text);
$text = implode(",",$textarray); //converts to comma delimited list

...store in database

...fetch from database and echo text back for editing

$text = $row['text'];
$text = str_replace( ",", "\n", $text);

echo '<textarea>'.$text.'</textarea>';
```

Comment: As i see, 'document.getElementById("droptext").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText' erases your 'text' texarea

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to this on another question.

[JavaScript: How to add line breaks to an HTML textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863779/textarea-line-breaks-javascript)

Javascript does not urlencode line breaks when it submits request to a server.  They basically disappear. So you need to do your own urlencoding in javascript prior to the request.

```
var text2 = text.replace("\n\r","&#13;&#10;");
```

Note, there is some suggestion in other discussion that urlencoding of POST and GET requests is handled differently in different languages but when I tested I did not ind any difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem about storing the whole content unmodified? I don't know what database you're using, but most should support the text field with line breaks.

If that's still a problem, maybe the problem is using "\r\n", can you show us what gets sent to the server?

Also your textarea returned by php is missign the id, that should prevent you from doing getText more than once.

Comment: When I store unmodified the text that comes back displays without lone breaks.  This is the rationale for converting them to commas which at least are visible ie unescaped so you can see them.  I don't know a good way to see escaped characters in what gets sent to the server. All I see is text. searching and replacing hidden characters is the only way I know to view thrm