# display text in multiline using text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using Text area tag in html and i have to print the ingredients in separate lines but even on using enter key it is coming in a single line  when i pass the value of text area to a variable and print it.

Following is my code snippet :

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="name">Ingredients</label>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="new_ingredients">

    </textarea>
</div>

$( '#new_recipe' ).live( 'pagebeforeshow',function(event){
    var temp1 = $("#new_ingredients").val();
    $("#testing").text(temp1);
});

<div data-role="page" id="new_recipe">
    <div class="content" id="testing" ></div>
</div>
```

Please help me as to how could i get  data in different lines when the user presses enter key.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just FYI live() is deprecated with the current version http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Have a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863779/textarea-line-breaks-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
$("#testing").html(temp1.replace(/\n\r?/g, "<br />"));
```

The characters that are represented by pressing the "enter" key in a textarea are represented with "\n" (sometimes with `\r` as well). But when displaying in HTML, they mean nothing more than a space, visually. To display these newlines, they need to be replaced with the HTML equivalent - `<br />` elements.

Since `<br />` elements are now being added to the `#testing` element's contents, you need to use `.html()`, not `.text()`. Otherwise, the HTML is escaped and won't display properly.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Wkbrn/2/

Comment: @knut i tried using the replace function but it is showing <br> tag in the div content along with the string  and  still not coming in separate lines.

Comment: @user2185012 Did you use `$("#testing").html()` instead of `$("#testing").text()` like I suggested? That's required in order to display the `<br />` HTML properly, and I explained it in the answer

Comment: @knut : Yes , i wasnt using .html and hence it wasn't working . Thank you :)

Comment: for better coverage use `replace(/(\n|\r|\r\n)/g, '<br>')` not just `/\n\r?/g`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="name">Ingredients</label>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="new_ingredients">ingredient1&#13;&#10;ingredient2&#13;&#10
        </textarea>
        </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var temp1 = $("#new_ingredients").html().replace(/\n/g,"<br>");;
 $("#testing").html(temp1);
})
</script>

<div data-role="page" id="new_recipe">
<div class="content" id="testing" ></div></div>
```

I have modified the script just for testing