# Enable Break Line or New Line in Textarea when press enter

Tags: textarea, newline, enter

How can i enable a **Break Line** or **New Line** in **Textarea** when i press the **Enter Key** ?
So that if I press the **ENTER** it saves in the form of **New Line** in database.

I have already searched some topics but it hasn't helped me.

**Here is my Textarea Code:**

```
<textarea name="post" id="post"  class="valid Post_Text_Area" placeholder="Write something here..." ></textarea>
```

**I tried this JS Code so far. but it hasn't worked for me**

[JavaScript: How to add line breaks to an HTML textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863779/textarea-line-breaks-javascript)

Comment: which technology do you use to save the text into the db?

Comment: I am using simple $_POST with Insert Query into MySQL DB

Comment: So **PHP**, If I am correct, the **new line** is saved into the database by default when coming from a `textarea`. If you want to display it into `html`, try using the function `nl2br($text)`

Comment: @Tikkes No PHP does not saves text coming from textarea in new lines. and nl2br() function is not working for me

Comment: As far as in my knowledge , some regular expression or jquery code will solve this problem

Comment: So show me how you save and display. Only those lines. Edit the post on top to include the save and display of the text saved in the db. And I will help you further. **edit** I also assume your database column is of type **TEXT**

Comment: @Tikkes Ok dear problem solved by nl2br() Function :)

Comment: I post this as an answer, please do accept

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Newlines in textarea's are saved into the database by default.

To generate them as Html **BR** codes, use `nl2br($yourTextVariable)` **$yourTextVariable** will be the variable you fetch from database. so use it like this :

```
<?php echo nl2br($yourTextVariable); ?>
```

This transforms `newline` to `<br />`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is put the output into `<pre>` tag or just style it with css `white-space: pre`. It will not swallow multiple spaces.

Comment: `<pre><?php echo htmlspecialchars($yourTextVariable) ?></pre>`. (Yes, don't forget to use `htmlspecialchars` or `strip_tags` if you don't want to allow http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).