# Editable div new line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code structure of an editable div, whose data I save using jquery and later on php, and later display in a different div and a different input field (a regular one, not an editable div).

If I enter 1 single line to the editable div everything works fine, but when I break lines using the ENTER key something weird happens, the breaked line is covered with `<div>...</div>` and there is no line break.
When I now save the text and display it I see the `<div>` tags instead of line breaks.

For example, if I enter
"this is one line
 this is a new line
 this is one more line"

what I get is the following: `"this is one line <div>this is a new line</div><div>this is one more line</div>"`

Not only that the 2 breaked lines are covered in divs, the first line isnt...
what I want to get is the content breaked with lines so that when I display it in another div and anothe input field I will see the line breaks.

Thanks in advance,
Gabi.

Comment: Code would be help everyone assist in solving your problem. Please post some.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863779/javascript-how-to-add-line-breaks-to-an-html-textarea