# How to separate paragraphs in a textbox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, line-breaks

If I have a textbox, and I want to generate some paragraph into it, it makes sense I will want to use linebreaks. Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66773/add-a-linebreak-in-an-html-text-area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your line break specify `Environment.NewLine` as in

```
Str = "This is a line" & Environment.NewLine & " and another " & Environment.NewLine
```

Use two NewLine for a paragraph separation

```
Para =  Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & "my para body" & Environment.NewLine &  Environment.NewLine
```

Put the text in your TextBox

```
myTxtbox.Text = Str
```

Answer (score 0):

Line breaks in VB.NET can be achieved with minimal code by using `vbcrlf`:

```
twoParagraphs = "Paragraph One..." & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Paragraph Two..."

aTextBox.Text = twoParagraphs
```

`vbcrlf` is essentially the same as `Environment.NewLine` but is specific to VB.NET

Comment: It's ugly and obsolete.  In fact, any decent refactoring tool would bug you to reconsider using vbcrlf constructions.  Environment.NewLine is culture-specific and it looks more professional.