# Using a line break in a text area 'value'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, simple-form

I am working on a simple private messaging application and, when replying to a message, I would like to display the original message a few spaces down in the text area. Here is what I am putting:

```
<%= f.input :content, :as=>:text, :label => "Reply", :input_html => { :value=> "<br /><br />Original Message: #{@message.content}".html_safe } %>
```

and.. here is what I'm seeing:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with `\n` instead of `<br/>`, and also, apply `html_safe` only to `@message.content`, not to the whole string:

```
<%= f.input :content, :as=>:text, :label => "Reply", :input_html => { :value=> "\n\nOriginal Message: " + @message.content.html_safe } %>
```

Comment: Value is not accepted to set the contents of textarea.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the [HTML standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-button-element.html#the-textarea-element) does not allow `textarea` elements to have any nested elements, only plain text is allowed.

To work around this you have to use normal line breaks via `\n`. ([See this existing SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66773/add-a-linebreak-in-an-html-text-area))

Comment: Thanks for that Daniel. I appreciate the background info. I gave Tudor the tick as he gave a perfect ruby/rails implementation which worked.. and provided the \n answer slightly before you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<%= f.input :content, :as=>:text, :label => "Reply", :input_html => { :value=> ("<br /><br />" +"Original Message: #{@message.content}".html_safe) } %>
```