# struggling with creating asterisks in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I've been struggling with this for some time now. What I wanted to create is to output a triangle of asterisks based on user's input. Let say user entered size 5, it would look something like this:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

My HTML looks like:

```
<p>
Size: <input type="text" id="size">
<input type="button" value="Draw" onclick="draw()">
</p>

<pre id="output">
</pre>
```

In my Javascript, I have:

```
function draw()
{
  var size = customJS.get ( "size" ); //I have a custom library where it get the Id from HTML
  var theTriangle = makeTriangle( size.value ); //sending in the size
  customJS.set ("output", theTriangle); //will set theTriangle to display to "output" in HTML
}

function makeTriangle( theSize )
{
    var allLines = "";    // an empty string to hold the entire triangle
    for ( var i = 0; i <= size; i++) // this loop size times
    {
        var oneLine = createLine ( i <= size ); // amount of asterisks for this line
        allLines += oneLine;
    }
    return allLines;
}

function createLine ( length )
{
    var aLine = "";     // an empty string to hold the contents of this one line
    for ( var j = 0; j <= i; j++ ) //this loop length times
    {
        aLine += '*';  
    }
    return aLine + "<br>";
}
```

anyone have any tip on how I go about this? thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Newlines in HTML normally display as spaces, but you want them to show as newlines. The `pre` tag makes newlines actually appear as new lines, so wrap the output in a `pre` tag:

```
customJS.set ("output", "<pre>" + theTriangle + "</pre>");
```

Also, you're calling `createLine` like this:

```
var oneLine = createLine ( i <= size );
```

`i <= size` yields a boolean (`true` or `false`) rather than a number. You probably mean to just pass it `i`:

```
var oneLine = createLine ( i );
```

Additionally, you're setting `size` like this:

```
var size = customJS.get = ( "size" );
```

You probably want to drop the second equals, since as is, it sets the variable `size` to the string `"size"`.

And finally, you've got a few variables wrong: in `makeTriangle`, you're looping `size` times, but `size` is undefined; you probably meant `theSize`. In `createLine`, you're looping `i` times, but `i` is undefined; you probably meant `length`.

With all that, [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/u6mjm/).

Comment: so i've changed to `var oneLine = createLine ( i );` but nothing happens when I click `Draw`

Comment: I believe that the `customJS.set` is not an issue in this function because I've used it for my other javascript and it works fine. The problem must be in the `makeTriangle` or `createLine` function, but I can't seem to figure it out...

Comment: @KennyWong: I just saw one more thing (the way you're assigning `size`) which I've added to my answer.

Comment: i got that fixed. But still nothing happens when I click Draw

Comment: WOW! amazing! can't believe it only takes you less than 30 min to figure it out, while I take several hours, just staring at it and wondering "what the heck I did wrong"? Thank you very much!!

Comment: do you also know how to place the output in a `div`? I added `<div id="div"> </div>` to the HTML and also `customJS.set ("div", theTriangle);` to the javascript code but instead, I got `* ** *** ****` with no linebreaks  if I input 4 as the size.

Comment: @KennyWong: For a `div`, you could use `<br>` rather than a line break, but I think a `pre` works well.

Comment: sorry to ask again, but how do I make it draw upside down? This is what I came up with but it's not working, http://jsfiddle.net/K8G78/1/

Comment: @KennethMa: First of all, you don't need to have a separate `createLine`. Second of all, it's `checked`, not `clicked`. Thirdly, rather than `>= 5` you probably want `>= 0`.

Answer (score 1):

There were several bugs in your code. For example using theSize instead size as parameter in the function makeTriangle(), using i instead of length in the createLine() function in the for loop condition.

Another one was:

use

```
return aLine + "<br/>";
```

instead of

```
return aLine + "\n";
```

The working solution for your code can be found in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwe_guenther/wavDH/): http://jsfiddle.net/uwe_guenther/wavDH/

And below is a copy of the fiddle:

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Size:
         <input type="text" id="sizeTextField">
         <input id='drawButton' type="button" value="Draw">
         <div id='output'></div>
    </p>

    <script src='main.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*main.js*

```
(function (document) {
    var drawButton = document.getElementById('drawButton'),
        sizeTextField = document.getElementById('sizeTextField'),
        output = document.getElementById('output');

    function makeTriangle(size) {
        var allLines = '';
        for (var i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
            var oneLine = createLine(i); // amount of asterisks for this line
            allLines += oneLine;
        }
        return allLines;
    }

    function createLine(length) {
        var aLine = '';
        for (var j = 0; j <= length; j++) {
            aLine += '*';
        }
        return aLine + "<br/>";
    }

    drawButton.onclick = function () {
        output.innerHTML = makeTriangle(sizeTextField.value);
    };
})(document);
```

Comment: You are welcome Kenny! You should just use some debugging technics, like for example console.log() together with Chrome devtools or Firefox with its web console or Firebug. There is also the god old alert() method working across all browsers. Chrome has also a full fledged debugger these days.

Comment: thanks for your advice. I got one more question, I tried to output it to a textarea but instead, I got `*<br/>**<br/>***<br/>****<br/>*****<br/><br/>` I don't know how to keep the formatting in a textarea.

Comment: Instead of "<br/>" use "&#013;&#010;" Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/uwe_guenther/wavDH/2/ Here you can read all the details about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66773/add-a-linebreak-in-an-html-text-area

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage some JavaScript tricks to make the code a bit more terse:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <label>Size:
        <input type="text" id="size" value="5">
    </label> <pre id='output'></pre>

</div>
<script>
    var size = document.getElementById('size'),
        output = document.getElementById('output');

    function update() {
        var width = +size.value, // Coerce to integer.
            upsideDown = width < 0, // Check if negative.
            width = Math.abs(width), // Ensure positive.
            treeArray = Array(width).join('0').split('0') // Create an array of 0s "width" long.
                .map(function(zero, level) { // Visit each one, giving us the chance to change it.
                    return Array(2 + level).join('*'); // Create a string of *s.
                });
        upsideDown && treeArray.reverse(); // If width was negative, stand the tree on its head.
        output.innerHTML = treeArray.join('\n'); // Join it all together, and output it!
    }

    size.onkeyup = update;
    update();
    size.focus();
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mhtKY/4/