# jQuery - Adding a line break when value is added to textarea

Tags: jquery

At present, when you click on the dropdown, select an option and click on any of the checkboxes, it adds a value to the textbox. However when I add a second value, it's entered directly next to the first value. How would i go about adding a line break?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luke_sully/5dbe7dgy/)

**jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.group').hide();
        $('#selectMe').change(function () {
            $('.group').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        })
    });

    var courses = {
        course1: 'BIS 445 UCC lvl8 ',
        course2: 'Commerce 475 UCC lvl8 ',
        course3: 'Economics 350 UCD lvl8 ',
        course4: 'Government 405 UL lvl8 ',
        course5: 'Medicine 600 UCC lvl8',
        course6: 'Nursing 500 UCC lvl8'
    }

    var $mytextbox = $('#courses');

    $("input[type='checkbox'][name*='course']").change(function () {
        var $chk = $(this);
        if ($chk.prop('checked')) {
            $mytextbox.val($mytextbox.val() + courses[$chk.attr('name')]);
        } else {
            $mytextbox.val($mytextbox.val().replace(courses[$chk.attr('name')], ""));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `<textarea>` inputs, a line break is created by inserting a `\n` at the end of the line, thus creating a new line.

Modify your code to look like the following:

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name*='course']").change(function () {
    var $chk = $(this);
    if ($chk.prop('checked')) {
        $mytextbox.val($mytextbox.val() + courses[$chk.attr('name')] + "\n");
    } else {
        $mytextbox.val($mytextbox.val().replace(courses[$chk.attr('name')] + "\n", ""));
    }
});
```

I've updated your JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5dbe7dgy/1/) to demo how this works. It's important to remember to update both the insert and removal of the `\n` character as the courses are checked and unchecked. Without inserting and removing the `\n` character in both places, you may experience undesired results such as multiple lines between courses.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a line feed. See:

[Add a linebreak in an HTML text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66773/add-a-linebreak-in-an-html-text-area)

"\n" or &vbCrLf

So something like

```
$mytextbox.val($mytextbox.val() + "\n" +  courses[$chk.attr('name')]);
```